# Is there an alternative for compiler directives in PHP in order to use app version?

Tags: php, version

Here is the thing, I have a running application and my client has been asking me to add features over time. Now he hasn't implemented all the features that I've developed, but he wants to implement one feature recently developed. The thing is that there could be some incompatibility issues between the versions of the application that I made.

I am wondering if I can add some sort of version directives to the methods of a class in php and somehow execute the ones that match with the web application version?

I would appreciate greatly any kind of help that you could give me.

Comment: Generally if you expect this to happen you should have tight version control so that you know what features will affect what.

Answer (score 1):

You can get PHP's currently running version from the version constant PHP_VERSION and use version_compare which might help you out with w/e you are trying to do: http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php

You can set you own version and then declare the appropriate class like this (your code need to know which copy of the class is running:

```
define("APPLICATION_VERSION", "1.23");
define("APPLICATION_VERSION_MAJOR", "1.");
define("APPLICATION_VERSION_MINOR", "23");
if (APPLICATION_VERSION_MAJOR == "1") {
    //version 1 class declaration here
    class hello {}
} else {
    //not version 1 class declaration here
    class hello {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a settings.php file and add constants to it.

**setting.php**

```
// Valid constant names
define("VERSION",     "1");
```

**class.php**

```
include('settings.php')

if (defined('VERSION') && VERSION == "1") {
    //run code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not a compiled language; just like it's client-side siblings (HTML et al.), each file is evaluated individually each time a page must be generated. So, the concept of having something in the file processed before the rest of the file loses its value rapidly.

That said, there are some variables that can be set before this process and stay constant throughout, and those are in **[php.ini](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)**. These are, by the literal definition, pre-processor directives. However, I know they're not what you're looking for.